# Any obvious reason that $\frac{\prod_{j\leq d}(q^{n+1}-q^j)}{\prod_{k\leq d}(q^{d+1}-q^k)}$ is an integer for $q$ a power of prime, $d\leq n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is there any obvious reason that $\frac{\prod_{j\leq d}(q^{n+1}-q^j)}{\prod_{k\leq d}(q^{d+1}-q^k)}$ is an integer where $q$ is a power of some prime for all $d\leq n,n\geq 1$?

I used cyclotomic field polynomial and argued that denominator's cyclotomic polynomials must be in the numerator's cyclotomic field polynomials by removing redundant extra factor of $q^j$ and $q^k$. Then the rest is algebraic number and by algebraic closureness of $Z$. I conclude the quotient must be in $Z$.(I need to extend the galois automorphism of cyclotomic fields by considering some large $\zeta_l$ cyclotomic field extension say $l=\prod_{j\leq d}(n+1-j)$.)

This is basically counting distinct $d$ dimension linear subspace of $P_n(F_q)$.

Comment: As you say, it's counting something.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes. It is counting something. However, it would be nicer to see this must be an integer. Suppose I am presented to this formula without context. It is hard for me to think this is counting $d$ dimension linear subspace of some projective space and unfortunately, integerness requires a proof.

Comment: You could look up "$q$-binomial coefficients*. If you compute these, you'll find they are polynomials in $q$ with positive integer coefficients....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this answers the question (but without needing $q$ to be a power of a prime, so I’m not sure): $\displaystyle\frac{\prod_{j\leq d}(q^{n+1}-q^j)}{\prod_{k\leq d}(q^{d+1}-q^k)}=\frac{\prod_{j\leq d}(q^{n+1-j}-1)}{\prod_{k\leq d}(q^{d+1-k}-1)}$, which is a $q$-binomial coefficient, therefore a polynomial.